# "Why did you call me?" or "Why have you called me?"

Tags: tense, past-vs-present-perfect

Here is a situation.

> Your phone rings and you answer the phone. And middle of the talk, you realize you don't have much time left. So you feel like needing to come down to the point. So you ask your friend on the phone by using one of these expressions:
> "Why did you call me?" or
> "Why have you called me?".

Which question sentence is more proper and why? One is simple past tense and the other is present perfect tense.

Comment: I'd say "why are you calling ?" because you are right in the middle of the conversation.

Comment: @Laura So neither of the suggested expressions can be used there? But, actually calling had started earlier than the conversation because dialing had been done earlier. Exactly how "calling" is defined here? The behavior of dialing and waiting for the conversation to start? Or does it include the whole package even including the whole conversation?

Comment: If you want to use past tense and present perfect, those are fine, but I think what Laure had been suggesting was that her phrase is the more idiomatic, commonly-used one. But that's just my own take of her comment :). I am not presuming to speak for her.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Aha, I have understood. Thanks. :)

Comment: "The behavior of dialing and waiting for the conversation to start" That's dialing, whereas calling evokes the notion of speaking. Waiting is doing nothing, by definition, so I wouldn't mention it. If you are unsure, though, you are right to say "to be calling" from picking up the phone to hanging up.

Comment: If I'd already been chatting away to someone for 5 minutes, I'd definitely say "Why did you call?" over "Why are you calling?" as in "Before we got diverted talking about X, why did you originally call me".

Comment: @anotherdave Thank you for providing another essential aspect in understanding it.

But there is something not yet concluded for me, as your logic, out of a first glimpse, seems to have some collision with others' explanations.

I'd like to ask you whether the following interpretation is correct: **the 1st scenario**: If the talk on the phone is consistent in one story, which was initially dialed for by the caller, then after 5 or even 30 minutes of talk the state should still be *to be calling*, **the 2nd scenario**: The one you presented in your comment.

Comment: @SmartHumanism, actually I think regardless of topic, I would use the past tense once the call is underway. E.g. as an opening to a conversation, if someone say "Hello, Smart Humanism? This is your son's school principal". I would reply "Hello, is everything OK? Why are you calling?" If my friend rang me & then changed topic about a dog starting to do a funny trick, I would say "I've got to go soon. Why did you call?". If my friend's car had broken down & I'm trying to figure out if they're just telling me or they need my help, I'd say "I've got to go soon. Did you need me to do anything?"

Comment: I don't think any of these are hard & fast 'rules' though, just what I'd naturally say. If someone said to me "Why are you calling?" after 5 minutes, I wouldn't think it unusual or that they'd made a mistake.

Comment: @anotherdave I really appreciate your replies very much.
But, I'd wish to get some points confirmed.

At the part in your reply ***Actually I think regardless of topic, I would use the past tense once the call is underway. E.g. as an opening to a conversation, if someone say "Hello, Smart Humanism? This is your son's school principal". I would reply "Hello, is everything OK? Why are you calling?*** I am a little confused, because you said you would use the **past tense** regardless whether or not the topic changes and then, your example is using the **to be calling** version.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was — if I was querying a call _just_ after answering, I would use the present tense: "Why are you calling?". But once the call was underway, I personally would switch to past tense: "Why were you calling?" / "Why did you call?" (either)

Comment: @anotherdave Thank you for clarifying. I assume that your point is not only applied to US English but to globally. I looked up the origin of **call** and it is *Old Norse kalla ‘summon loudly’*. So if the origin still has some stake in the current version of **call**, then, as you said, once the counterpart has been summoned, the past tense would be the right one to be used in this manner.

Comment: @SmartHumanism I'm over the other side :) — an Irishman in Britain last 10 years — so what I've said would be fairly "standard" for BrEng, but can't comment to US usage.  I would say though that at least in this case (for 'to call') it's a general feel rather than a hard rule — would be interesting to post another Q if you'd other scenarios in mind that you wanted to generalise to. Even without Old Norse, call in English can generally be used for "summon loudly", e.g. you might say "Call your brother in from the garden. Let him know the dinner is ready".

Comment: @anotherdave Thank you very much for adding more necessary helpful explanation. Yes, I have definitely grasped the feel of ***summon loudly*** from your comment. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first meaning of the verb *call* is to use your voice to draw someone's attention. In relation to using the phone it can be used for the actual fact of dialling the number (and possibly not getting through...) as well as for the fact of having a conversation over the phone with someone whose number you have just dialled (you would not use it if you were on the receiving end).

In your example I personally think there are three possibilities.
If you want to refer to the actual fact of dialling the number then of course the choice has to refer to the past, by way of either using the past or the present perfect. I would use the present perfect because it is the tense that links a past action to the present, and the telephone call is still ongoing. But there might be local usages (US I think, but I'm not an expert on US English)  that would tolerate the past.

I would use the present V-ing form because I consider that the act of calling covers the act of dialling the number + the act of talking to the recipient. Moreover in your particular example where you want the caller to come quickly to the point, using the present V-ing helps bring the caller back into the urgency of the action. So, I'd say :

> Why are you calling?

Comment: A perfect answer I have never seen before. Thank you for the kind, best answer, the perfect Laure.

Comment: @SmartHumanism, I would have said: A more perfect answer I have never seen (before). It's the "more" that makes this answer the most perfect answer that you have ever seen.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang: I was taught perfect had no comparative form. Either something is complete or not. If you want to compare, better use *better*. A better comment would be more modest. (I'm doing it myself you see, I have actual reason to complain).

Comment: @Hectorvon, sorry, I should have been more clear. I had been commenting on the idiom itself, which is "[a more perfect (noun)](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=a+more+perfect+i+have+never+seen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YvTIWJOBHcX48AfvqYe4Dw)." But yes, of course, you're right: Semantically, what could be more perfect than perfection itself :).